# avoid SD card corruption in ansi C

Tags: c, file-io, sd-card, embedded-linux, can-bus

I am currently working on an embedded Linux device for data logging. The Linux device is plugged into a CANbus and writes the traffic to an SD card.

From time to time the SD card corrupts and is mounted read-only.  This behavior needs to be avoided.

The file system is FAT (the SD card should stay be readable by windows systems).

The embedded device can power fail any time, so I need a safe way to write to the SD card from my C program.

As I am not really into C, I rely on a program called "candump" which basically prints the canmessages to stdout in this format:

```
<0x006> [8] 77 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

My C program basically opens the candump program, reads from stdout, adds a timestamp and removes unnecessary chars:

```
1345836055.520 6 7700000000000000


while(running)
{
    if (filename != NULL)
    {
        fp_log = fopen(filename, "a");
        if (!fp_log) 
        {
            perror("fopen");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }  
    }  

    fgets(line, sizeof(line)-1, fp);

    /* reset the row_values so they are always correctly initialized */
    row_identifier = 0;

    if (strchr(line,'<') != NULL)
    {
        /* creating a buffer char to store values for casting char to int*/
        buffer_ident[0] = line[4];
        buffer_ident[1] = line[5];

        /* cast buffer e.g. {'1','0','\0'} to int: 10 */
        row_identifier = strtol(buffer_ident,NULL,10);

        /* heartbeat of the CANBUS PLC */
        if(row_identifier == 80)
        {
            /* return pong on identifier 81 to the PLC */
            //system("cansend can0 -i 81 1 > /dev/null");
        }
        else
        {
            gettimeofday(&tv,NULL);
            fprintf(fp_log,"%d.%03d ", tv.tv_sec, tv.tv_usec/1000);
            fprintf(fp_log,"%d ",row_identifier);

            /* rowlenght > 11 = data part is not empty */
            row_lenght = strlen(line);
            if (row_lenght>11)
            {
                int i=0;
                for (i=11;i<row_lenght;i++)
                    /* remove spaces between the data to save space and copy data into new array */
                    if (isspace(line[i]) == 0)
                        fprintf(fp_log,"%c",line[i]);
            fprintf(fp_log,"\n");   
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(fp_log);

}
```

The code snippet above works fine, its just that I get SD card corruption.

**Solution**

I ended up using ext3 as the file system with standard mount options. No problems any more

Comment: are you sure the corruption does not happens elsewhere?

Comment: this is the only program accessing the sd card so i haven't considered that the corruption could happen elsewhere. and to be honest i dont know where to start or track down the corruption

Comment: /var/log/ is a good place to start digging to find the root of the SD card issues (some embedded systems do not log stuff by default/at all)

Comment: Just a guess .... try `fsync(fp_log)` before you close it and mount the sd card with `-o flush`

Comment: what happens if the embedded device is switched off before the code reaches fclose(fp_log)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The corruption probably happens because the OS didn't complete its write operations on the FAT filesystem. As correctly pointed out by [J-16 SDiZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88442/j-16-sdiz) you can try to mitigate the problem doing `sync` from time to time to force the OS to write changes on the filesystem.

However, you are having this kind of problems because you are not using a journaled filesystem (such as Ext3 or NTFS. Another thing to do, could be to `fsck` the filesystem every boot and then explicitly forcing a `rw` remount to keep the mountpoint clean and writeable.

Comment: FAT: Filesystem error (dev mmcblk0p1)
    clusters badly computed (56 != 55)
FAT: Filesystem has been set read-only. this is the error message i just forced (unplugging sd card while logging) i will try ext3 file system

Comment: I don't have much experience with Fat32 errors under Linux, however I'd suggest to move to Ext3 to cut off these errors. If you need to frequently remove the SD card and read it under Windows you can try to use [IFS Drivers](http://www.fs-driver.org/). Another way to satisfy this requirement could be to set up a CIFS mountpoint such as `//192.168.1.1/shared /mnt/shared cifs default,noauto,user=guest,pass=guest 0 0`

Answer (score 0):

Does the corruption happen even if you *don't* remove power? The above code is user-level only and doing simple `FILE *` operations; it shouldn't be able to corrupt the device.

If it is, then either the device driver itself is buggy, or something else is going on.

Can you check whether there are power problems, that might cause resets, for instance?

Comment: thank you for your input. power fails can occur because the emebedded device is power by a PLC, that controles a industrial crane. if the ignition of that crane is turned off the plc goes down and so the embedded device and it happens quite often.